# CUDA visual profiler error in reading profiler output

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia, profiler

I setup CUDA toolkit 3.0 ( window 7 64 bit ) and use CUDA Visual Profiler to analyze my CUDA project. It work so good with some normal project. But when I regroup those project together, Visual Profiler have an eror :  error in reading profiler output.
   How can I result this eror ? I was setup CUDA SDK and coding with it by 6 months ago, and now I have setup CUDA toolkit, can it not compatible with each other ?

Comment: CUDA toolkit 3.0?  What is that?  Are you talking about CUDA 3.0 from around 2009?  It's not clear what you mean by CUDA SDK and CUDA toolkit.  Are you referring to an [nsight VSE](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition) version number?

Comment: I was setup CUDA 5.0 and coding with it by 6 months ago, now I want to analyze my CUDA project with CUDA visual profiler, but I don't know how to use it with CUDA 5.0, so I setup CUDA toolkit 3.0 to use visual profiler of 3.0.   You can help me to analyze my project ?